# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I copied [this example](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/S3BackgroundTransfer-Sample/Objective-C) to a new project and am unable download from the same S3 bucket that worked with the example.

The pod being used is [this](https://cocoapods.org/?q=awss3) AWSS3 pod (v2.3.0).  I'm trying to isolate what might be different from the example app and my basic app.  There seem to be suggestions of having to modify my `Info.plist` file to be more permissive?

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered this little bit of unmentioned magic.  It looks like the sample app made special exceptions for contacting aws endpoints:

[image]